# ASP.NET SelectCommand (if type of statement)

Tags: asp.net

I have the following SelectCommand. I am trying to do 2 things.

First if

```
    GroupId = @GroupId and LocationId = @LocationId
```

then do that.

If that does not exist then do just do the following:

```
    GroupId = @GroupId.

   SelectCommand= "SELECT * FROM [mkTp] WHERE ([GroupId] = @GroupId  and LocationId = @LocationId) OR  ([GroupId] = @GroupId)"
```

This does not seem to work. Is there a way to do this. This is kind of like an if statement

Please find additional info below:

```
     <SelectParameters>             
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlM" Name="GroupId" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  Type="String"/>
      </SelectParameters>


    Note that  the ddlMu has the following info:

     Text = "Please Select",
      Value = "0"
```

Comment: can you post actual code?  I'm pretty sure that code doesn't compile.  Show what you are doing right now in code so we can help address your exact needs.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your SQL query. it should work fine. as @AdamHeeg said, please share the rest of your code.